# Select random record from mysql with multiple filters

Tags: mysql, performance, random

I know this was discussed many times but my research did not help me with my problem.

I have a table (innodb) with about 3k records. I need to pick 1 row random with some filters, which i do it like this:

```
select id, title, topic_id 
from posts 
where id not in 
(select post_id from records where user_id='$my_id' and checked='1') 
and topic_id='$topic_id' and status='1' 
order by RAND() limit 1
```

This gives me the result i wanted. The problem is this takes too much time even with 3k records. It will get slower when records are increased.

I have to find a solution for this. Any suggestions?

Update: Both tables are indexed with id columns.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this before writing here in the first place. But this didn't help me because of my WHERE filters

Comment: 3K rows in which table?  How many rows in the other table?

Comment: 3k rows in posts table. records table has 8k rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `where id not in`, I would use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT id, 
    title,
    topic_id 
FROM posts p
    LEFT JOIN records r
        ON p.id = r.post_id
            AND r.user_id='$my_id'
            AND r.checked = '1'
WHERE p.topic_id='$topic_id'
    AND status='1'
    AND r.post_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

With this, you will want an index on `posts.id` and another index on `records.post_id, records.user_id, records.checked`

Comment: I think this is an alternative to "where id in".
my query is "id not in"

Comment: @ozn `WHERE id IN` would be an `INNER JOIN`, while this is using a `LEFT JOIN .... WHERE NULL`, equivalent to `WHERE id NOT IN`

Comment: I will try this and tell the result. btw, what do you think about the table type? Is innodb ok for this action?

Comment: your query works as slow as mine. no remarkable speed up :(

Comment: @ozn can you update your question with your indexes?

Comment: Both tables are indexed with id columns. Is this what you are asking man?

Comment: InnoDB is the preferred Engine to use these days.

Comment: He's asking if `records` has `INDEX(post_id, user_id, checked)` (in any order).  That's important to performance.

Comment: Right indexing solved the problem. Thanks for your help friends.